# Unable to filter nested object element using typescript in angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to remove an element from an nested object using typescript. The option that i have tried doesn't seem to filter and the other options are giving me 
syntatical error. Could somebody tell me what the problem could be

```
this.results is of the type   public results: Array<NpvAnalysisResult> = [];
```

NpvAnalysisResult

```
export interface NpvAnalysisResult extends NpvAnalysis {
    captiveNetCost: number;
    commNetCost: number;
    selfNetCost: number;
    captiveInsPremiumPaidTotal: number;
    captiveInsTaxDeductionTotal: number;
    captiveInsLoanToParentTotal: number;
    captiveInsCapitalContributionTotal: number;
    captiveDividentDistributionTotal: number;
    captiveInsTerminalValueTotal: number;
    commInsPremiumPaidTotal: number;
    commInsTaxDeductionTotal: number;
    selfInsDiscountedLossesPaidTotal: number;
    selfInsDiscountedTaxDeductionTotal: number;
    boxplotChartSeries: any[];
}
```

NpvResults

```
NpvAnalysis extends NpvResults

export interface NpvAnalysis extends NpvResults {
    strategyName: string;
}
```

export interface NpvResults  {

```
    commInsYear: number[];
    commInsPremiumPaid: number[];
    commInsTaxDeduction: number[];
    commInsDiscountedTaxDeduction: number[];
    commInsDiscountedLossesPaid: number[];
    commInsGraphData: number[];
    selfInsYear: number[];
    selfInsDiscountedLossesPaid: number[];
    selfInsDiscountedTaxDeduction: number[];
    selfInsGraphData: number[];
    captiveInsYear: number[];
    captiveInsPremiumPaid: number[];
    captiveInsTaxDeduction: number[];
    captiveInsLoanToParent: number[];
    captiveInsCapitalContribution: number[];
    captiveDividentDistribution: number[];
    captiveInsTerminalValue: number[];
    captiveInsGraphData: number[];
    chartSeries: SeriesGeneric<BoxPlotSeriesData>;
}
```

BoxPlotSeriesData interface

```
export interface BoxPlotSeriesData  {

    low: number;
    q1: number;
    median: number;
    q3: number;
    high: number;
    color: string;
    name: string;
}

class SeriesGeneric<T> { 

    public data: T[];
}
```

Code while debugging

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I am trying to filter using the following code below but it doesnt seem to filter.

```
this.results.filter(x=> x.chartSeries.data.find(x=> x.name === 'Commercial Option'));
```

output of the property

```
Array(3) [Object, Object, Object]
length:3
__proto__:Array(0) [, …]
0:Object {commInsYear: Array(15), commInsPremiumPaid: Array(15), commInsTaxDeduction: Array(15), …}
captiveDividentDistribution:Array(16) [0, 0, 0, …]
captiveDividentDistributionTotal:0
captiveInsCapitalContribution:Array(16) [200000, 0, 0, …]
captiveInsCapitalContributionTotal:200000
captiveInsGraphData:Array(5) [1388107.00397383, 1391311.48360946, 1392127.30966767, …]
captiveInsLoanToParent:Array(16) [-111.240737236554, -108.323486790662, -105.436616545005, …]
captiveInsLoanToParentTotal:-1282.248023850004
captiveInsPremiumPaid:Array(16) [131898.108682546, 132963.002657693, 134038.336769846, …]
captiveInsPremiumPaidTotal:2095178.5368629089
captiveInsTaxDeduction:Array(16) [-27698.6028233354, -27922.2305581151, -28148.0507216675, …]
captiveInsTaxDeductionTotal:-439987.4927412096
captiveInsTerminalValue:Array(16) [0, 0, 0, …]
captiveInsTerminalValueTotal:-461755
captiveInsYear:Array(16) [1, 2, 3, …]
captiveNetCost:1392153.7960978495
chartSeries:Object {data: Array(3)}
    data:Array(3) [Object, Object, Object]
    length:3
    __proto__:Array(0) [, …]
    0:Object {low: 1388107.00397383, q1: 1391311.48360946, median: 1392127.30966767, …}
    1:Object {low: 0, q1: 0, median: 0, …}
    color:"#C111A0"
    high:0
    low:0
    median:0
    name:"Commercial Option"
    q1:0
    q3:0
    __proto__:Object {constructor: , __defineGetter__: , __defineSetter__: , …}
    2:Object {low: 21503.9638877926, q1: 24305.1060722588, median: 25003.3902831156, …}
  [1]: https://i.stack.img
```

ur.com/GaIoZ.png

Comment: The whole logic flow is not easy to follow (and I think there might be some missing pieces), where's the `data` property coming from? I can't see it anywhere in your interfaces

Comment: Update the post to see definition of the data and also output of the filter

Comment: Itried this but it didnt work    return this.results.filter(result => !!result.chartSeries.data.find(child => child.name === 'Commercial Option'));

Answer (score 0):

You should post your code as code, not as an image.

And you need to give the result of the `filter` to a variable like this :

```js
results = [{
  id: 0,
  children: [
    {id: 0},
    {id: 1},
    {id: 2},
  ]
}, {
  id: 1,
  children: [
    {id: 0},
    {id: 1},
    {id: 2},
  ]
}, {
  id: 2,
  children: [
    {id: 3},
    {id: 4},
    {id: 5},
  ]
}];

// Find every result that has a child with ID = 1
const found = this.results.filter(result => !!result.children.find(child => child.id === 1));

// Find every result that has not a child with ID = 1
const invertFound = this.results.filter(result => !result.children.filter(child => child.id === 1).length);

console.log(found);
console.log(invertFound);
```

Comment: I tried this but it didnt work return this.results.filter(result => !!result.chartSeries.data.find(child => child.name === 'Commercial Option'));

Comment: what does `didn't work` means. I just proved you it works. Be more specific, and provide a [mcve] on stackblitz

Comment: In you code you are filtering the last element completely as it is not having a child id ==1 . What I am looking for is to not remove the object on a whole but only the child that matches the id .

Comment: You can't remove a child by using a `filter` on the parent.

Comment: So for e.g i am looking at  id: 2,
  children: [
    {id: 4},
    {id: 5}]

Comment: I edited my answer to your use case @Tom, feel free to check it out.

Comment: Not sure why its not working for me. The invert function is removing all the elements. I mean by results array is of zero length. Is it an issue with string comparison. Your example is doing number

Comment: Yeah well you don't put your data in your question. Try making a case insensitive comparison with `toLowerCase/toUpperCase`, that's all I can tell you.

Comment: Yes. I did try that return this.results.filter(result => !result.chartSeries.data.filter(child => child.name.toUpperCase().trim() === 'COMMERCIALOPTION'));

Comment: Please make a [mcve] on stackblitz with your issue. It will be easier for me to help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173225/discussion-between-tom-and-trichetriche).

Comment: i have created a skeleton of the code on stackblitz. Wasnt sure how to populate the data https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-whn15y  . Hope that helps you to find a solution

Comment: You used my code in it ... I am aware my code works, what I want is your code that isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found the answer

```
get chartSeries() : Array<NpvAnalysisResult> {
    if(!this.CommercialPremium) {

      return this.results.map(x=> {
        const i = x.chartSeries.data.findIndex(y => y.name.toUpperCase() === 'COMMERCIAL OPTION');
        if (i > -1) {
          x.chartSeries.data.splice(i, 1);
        }
        return x;
      });
```